# HTML graph in rmarkdown PDF size is too small

Tags: html, r, pdf, r-markdown, plotly

I'm trying to get an HTML graph in a PDF output with `rmarkdown`:

````
---
title: "Test report"
output: pdf_document
always_allow_html: yes
params:
  plot: NA
---


```{r, echo=FALSE,message=FALSE, fig.height=4, fig.width=10, fig.show='hold'}
library(plotly)
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
plot_ly(d, x = ~carat, y = ~price, color = ~carat,
        size = ~carat, text = ~paste("Clarity: ", clarity))
```
````

Works fine as html output but when it's in pdf the graph is very small. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to use an interactive plot in a static pdf document? I would recommend using base R's plotting routines or `ggplot2` for any static plots.

Comment: The client wants a PDF and an HTML report and they need to look similar. I tried ``ggplot2`` but wasn't able to replicate the graphs.

Comment: I understand. But `plotly` is really meant for interactive documents. I usually generate my plots with `ggplot`, and then if necessary create an interactive version by wrapping it inside function `ggplotly`. The formatting will be very similar for both the static and interactive plots.

Comment: I should clarify that you *can* use `plotly` for generating static plots in PDFs (see e.g. [here](https://plot.ly/python/pdf-reports/)); however, the layout and formatting is probably easier to tune when taking the `ggplot` + `ggplotly` route, and it ensures consistent plots across PDF and HTML outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MauritsEvers. Caveat for me is that I use dygraphs, highcharter, plotly and html maps in my document. Just in this example I have mentioned a ``plotly`` example.

Comment: In that case, having [output-dependent plotting routines](https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/rmarkdown-alter-action-depending-on-document/) might be a way forward. This will also depend on the plotting routines you are using. For example, I'm not sure `highcharter` will allow you to produce static plots...

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and resolved by adding `out.width = "100%"` in `opts_chunk`:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = ">",
  out.width = "100%"
)
```